# Extract folder names inside of *.rar and *.zip files

Tags: r, data.table, zip, unzip, data-extraction

I have a folder with multiple *.rar and *.zip files.
Each *.rar and *.zip files have one folder and inside this folder have multiples folders.

I would like to generate a dataset with the names of these multiple folders.

How can I do this using R?

I trying:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern = "\\.zip$")
lapply(temp, function(x) unzip(x, list = T))
```

But it returns:

[image]

I would like to get just the names: "Nova pasta1" and Nova pasta2"

Thanks

Comment: Why not just unzip and use `list.dirs()`?

Comment: I have a lot of zip files with huge folders and files inside them.
I don't think that unzip all is a better way.
I would just need to get the names of the folders in it.

Comment: Here are some helpful links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099468/getting-zip-rar-structure-without-full-downloading https://osxdaily.com/2013/06/17/view-zip-archive-contents-without-extracting-mac-os-x/ . If you want to run in R, you can use system(command, intern = TRUE) and work with the output as a text file.

Comment: `<- unzip(my_zipped.zip, list = TRUE)` returns df (metadata), without uncompressing.

Comment: Your edit to the question just changed the substance of the question pretty substantially. See my answer below, which both addresses the original question and your new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create an simple set of directories/files that are representative of your own. You described having a **single** .zip file that contains **multiple** zipped directories, which may contain unzipped files and/or sub-directoris.

```r
# Example main directory
dir.create("main_dir")

# Example directory with 1 file and a subdirectory with 1 file
dir.create("main_dir/example_dir1")
write.csv(data.frame(x = 5), file = "main_dir/example_dir1/example_file.csv")
dir.create("main_dir/example_dir1/example_subdir")
write.csv(data.frame(x = 5), file = "main_dir/example_dir1/example_subdir/example_subdirfile.csv")

# Example directory with 1 file
dir.create("main_dir/example_dir2")
write.csv(data.frame(x = "foo"), file = "main_dir/example_dir2/example_file2.csv")

# NOTE: I was having issues with using `zip()` to zip each directory
# then the main (top) directory, so I manually zipped them below.

# Manually zip example_dir1 and example_dir2, then zip main_dir at this point.
```

Given this structure, we can get the paths to all of the directories within the highest level directory (`main_dir`) using `unzip(list = TRUE)` since we know the name of the single zipped directory containing all of these additional zipped sub-directories.

```r
# Unzip the highest level directory available, get all of the .zip dirs within
ex_path <- "main_dir"
all_zips <- unzip(zipfile = paste0(ex_path, ".zip"), list = TRUE)
all_zips

# We can remove the main_path string if we want so that we only
# the zip files within our main directory instead of the full path.
library(dplyr)

all_zips %>%
  filter(Name != paste0(ex_path, "/")) %>%
  mutate(Name = sub(paste0(ex_path, "/"), "", Name))
```

If you had multiple zipped directories with nested directories similar to `main_dir`, you could just put their paths in a list and apply the function to each element of the list. Below I reproduce this.

```r
# Example of multiple zip directory paths in a list
ziplist  <- list(ex_path, ex_path, ex_path)

lapply(ziplist, function(x) {
  temp <- unzip(zipfile = paste0(x, ".zip"), list = TRUE)
  temp <- temp %>% mutate(main_path = x)
  temp <- temp %>% 
           filter(Name != paste0(ex_path, "/")) %>%
           mutate(Name = sub(paste0(ex_path, "/"), "", Name))
  temp
})
```

If all of the .zip files in the current working directory are files you want to do this for, you can get `ziplist` above via:

```r
list.files(pattern = ".zip") %>% as.list()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is almost it. But I would like to get just the names, in your amazing example, of directories into the main_dir (example_dir1 and example_dir2).

Comment: Where I wrote "can remove the main path if we want" it will do that. just throw that into the lapply. I'll update to show

Comment: @WilsonSouza The above will produce an object with `example_dir1` and `example_dir2.`  You can extract that specific vector of values with `all_zips$Name`. If you wanted to drop the ".zip" from the directory, just use the same string substitution approach I employed above:  `all_zips$Name %>% sub(".zip","",.)`

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all help, but I think that I found a short way to solve my question.

```
temp.zip <- list.files(pattern = ".zip")
temp.rar <- list.files(pattern = ".rar")

mydata <- lapply(c(temp.rar, temp.zip),
                 function(x) unique(c(na.omit(str_extract(unlist
                                                          (untar(tarfile = x, 
                                                                 list = TRUE)),
                                                          '(?<=/).*(?=/)')))))

unlist(mydata)
```

Thanks all